# Offcanvas - CSS transition bug on Android 4.1.x

Tags: html, css, menu, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a offcanvas menu similar to Google Plus app's one.

Basically, I have a code working on almost all devices (android/ios) and browsers (ff, chrome, IE8+)

The only problem I have is on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 running Android 4.1.2 : if I activate the opacity transition of the dark/opaque layer on the right, the offcanvas menu won't hide when closing the menu ... and it totally breaks my app.

See this two fiddles on Android 4.1.2 :

- doesn't work : http://jsfiddle.net/F3BPw/3/
- works but I disabled to opacity transition (which I need) : http://jsfiddle.net/F3BPw/2/

Related CSS code (SASS version here, CSS version on jsfiddle) :

ps: see the two transitions lines commented , the bug appears If I decomment them

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /*height: 100%;*/
}

.sidebar-offcanvas {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

a[data-toggle=offcanvas]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

$global-site-min-height: 520px; /*TODO: replace this by better css or JS*/
#sidebar {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    min-height: $global-site-min-height;
    background-color: lighten($gray-light, 30%);

    .left-sidebar {
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
}

#rightpanel {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: $global-site-min-height;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: $screen-xs-max) {

    $sidebar-width: 40%;

    #togleSidebar {
        display: block;
    }

    .sidebar-offcanvas {
        @include transition(left 0.15s linear, opacity 0.15s linear);
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9500;
        top: 0;
        width: $sidebar-width;
        left: -$sidebar-width;
    }

    #rightpanel-shadow {
        background: #000 !important;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        visibility: hidden;
        @include opacity(0);
        z-index: 9250;
        @include transition(opacity 0.15s linear); /* SECOND FIDDLE WORKS IF COMMENTED*/
    }

    .active {
        .sidebar-offcanvas {
            left: 0;
            @include box-shadow(6px 0px 6px -2px #111111);
            @include transition(left 0.15s linear, opacity 0.15s linear);

        }

        #rightpanel-shadow {
            visibility: visible;
            @include opacity(0.75);
            transition-delay: 0s;
            zoom: 1;
            @include transition(opacity 0.15s linear); /* SECOND FIDDLE WORKS IF COMMENTED*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What browser are you testing on ? Chrome or "Samsung Browser" ? The latter is full of weird unresolved bugs, poor support for multiple animations (which you use) is one of them.

Comment: Yeah Samsung stock Browser :/ Unfortunately I must handle this crappy browser and desactivate transition for all other browsers.. unless I find a css trick or check user agent (last option)

Comment: Unfortunately user agent is also completely broken on Samsung stack browser. Some versions are an exact copy of Chrome user agent, some versions are not. Try one device and get mad, try five devices and get crazy. See answer below for a desperate solution.

Comment: I think that I'm having the same problem on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 with Android 4.2.2, if I set transition on an element I am not able to set the height of that element any more. Weird bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try avoiding multiple animations declarations like

```
transition: left 0.15s linear, opacity 0.15s linear;
```

Instead add a new nested element and give it the other animation.

Samsung default browser really doesn't do well with multiple animation (Until v4.0 Android was totally unable to handle this, nowadays Samsung browser still runs VERY old code).