# Transform not working on Android

Tags: android, css, css-animations, css-transforms

UPDATE:

i have changed this animation declaration instead of `animation: rotate linear infinite;` with no effect (website uploaded, you can see live on it link below)

```
.initialLoader, .initialLoader:before, .initialLoader:after {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.05s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 1.05s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

 content: '';
}
```

---

I am not very familiar with transitions and transforms in CSS, and so I have this question:

If you open [www.germanalvarez.net/5](http://www.germanalvarez.net/5) from any browser, you'll see circular bars loading animation (named rotate), and then another smart cursor pulsing animation (named pulse).

Both work from Chrome and Firefox but the first one does not work on my Android (Galaxy GT-I9300 (android 4.3), if I access the site trough my mobile device it just animates nothing, but the second one does. I can't find where the bug is.

Live demo in [www.germanalvarez.net/5](http://www.germanalvarez.net/5)

HTML:

```
<div class="initialLoader"></div>
<div class="initialHi"><div class='initialAnimation'><ul class='letters'></ul><div class='cursor'></div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.initialLoader, .initialLoader:before, .initialLoader:after {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
     -webkit-animation: rotate linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: rotate linear infinite;
   -ms-animation: rotate linear infinite;
   -o-animation: rotate linear infinite;
  animation: rotate linear infinite;

     -webkit-animation-duration: 1.05s;
-moz-animation-duration: 1.05s;
   -ms-animation-duration: 1.05s;
   -o-animation-duration: 1.05s;
   animation-duration: 1.05s;
 content: '';
}

.initialLoader {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
     position:absolute;
   margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.05s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.05s;
   -ms-animation-duration: 1.05s;
   -o-animation-duration: 1.05s;
   animation-duration: 1.05s;
}

.initialLoader:before {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
   -ms-animation-duration: 10s;
   -o-animation-duration: 10s;
   animation-duration: 10s;


}

.initialLoader:after {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 22px;
  left: 22px;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
   -ms-animation-duration: 4s;
   -o-animation-duration: 4s;
   animation-duration: 4s;


}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {   -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);  }
  to {    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);  }
}


@keyframes rotate {
  from {    transform: rotateZ(360deg);  }
  to {    transform: rotateZ(0deg);  }
}



.initialAnimation{
   font-family: 'Electrolize',Arial;
   color:white;
   cursor:pointer;
   font-size:1.3em;
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}


.initialHi{
      position:absolute;
   margin: -15px 0 0 -60px;
width:120px; height:auto;
top:50%;
   left:50%;


}

.cursor{
   opacity:0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 1.3em;
  background-color:white;
  margin-top: -6px; 
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
     -moz-animation: appear 0.1s linear 1 normal;
   -webkit-animation: pulse  0.4s linear infinite normal;
   -ms-animation: pulse  0.4s linear infinite normal;
   -o-animation: pulse  0.4s linear infinite normal;
   animation: pulse  0.4s linear infinite  normal;

  }




@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 2px rgba(105,135,255,1);  }
  100% {    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 2px rgba(105,135,255,0.3);  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 2px rgba(105,135,255,1);  }
  100% {    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 2px rgba(105,135,255,0.3);  }
}
```

Comment: which Android do you use?

Comment: Galaxy GT-I9300 (android 4.3)

Comment: oh... sorry. the browser's preinstalled one, its just called 'internet', and version 4.3-I9300xxugna5

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22534605/188331)

Comment: I am about to try separating each animation aspect

Comment: Please @Raptor see updated info